# How to add a load balancer at a later stage and re-configure DNS without downtime?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, load-balancing

Say I deploy an API, the database etc. to a t2.micro EC2 instance to serve traffic for the period of prototyping and beta testing. Let's say the domain pointing to the API is api.exampleapp.com.

Now traffic begins to grow beyond the instance's limits and we deploy the API to a bunch of instances that we want to stand behind a load balancer. After setting the fleet up, how do we make api.exampleapp.com point now to the load balancer's IP address so that traffic is served by the newly launched instances without any downtime? Is this possible at all? Or with minimal downtime? Or is this approach of starting up with a new API itself faulty?

Comment: Keep in mind to not to store application specific data(i.e uploaded files, session storage) on cluster nodes, otherwise each API Server will be serving different data according to what it has in its storage.
Or else, use sticky sessions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you either don't need auto-scaling or have it already configured.

1. start the LB and attach your first EC2 to it. The instance still work, can be directly accessible via its IP (thus, accessible from the World).
2. check the LB hostname, try to access the instance using LB, make sure it works
3. switch DNS to the LB using either CNAME or ALIAS record type (if ALIAS is supported by your DNS server)
4. add another instances to the LB.

Done!